# Debian start-stop-daemon. What is the purpose of oknodo option?

Tags: linux, debian, command

According to man start-stop-daemon

> -o, --oknodo
> Return exit status 0 instead of 1 if no actions are (would be) taken.

What is the purpose of this option? When is it used?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `--oknodo` is to avoid failing when the system is already in the requested state. For example, if you write an init script using `start-stop-daemon`, the behaviour [specified by Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#writing-the-scripts) is that the `start` action should *not* fail if the dæmon is already running, and `stop` should *not* fail if the dæmon is already stopped; the `--oknodo` option provides this behaviour.

The option exists because `start-stop-daemon` is intended to be more generic than only supporting init scripts. Thus the default is to fail if it doesn’t do what was requested of it.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Does this mean that if using start-stop-daemon on Debian, we should always use --oknodo to follow Debian policy? If so, the man page is not clear about this.

Comment: If you’re using `start-stop-daemon` in an init script, then yes, you should always use `--oknodo`. As I mentioned in the answer, `start-stop-daemon` is more generic than only Debian and only init scripts, which is presumably why the documentation doesn’t refer to Policy; it’s also unusual for a man page to explain how to use a tool in a Policy-compliant fashion. Note however that all the examples in the man page use `--oknodo`.